# Elegant way to include es6-promise for IE

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

Since `Promise` is [not support](http://caniuse.com/#search=promise) in all IE versions, I would like to make the IE users to download a pollyfill in HTML.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/4.1.1/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

However, [conditional comments are not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx) in IE 10 and 11. So the above code doesn't work in IE 10 and 11.

Then, Microsoft provide a workaround.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

This make IE 10 and 11 behave like IE 9.

But my website work only in IE 10+. So this solution isn't suitable to me.
Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to request the `.js` file at only ie?

Comment: @guest271314 "*I would like to make the IE users to download a pollyfill*"

Comment: @Bergi You quoted the requirement then proceeded to exceed the boundaries that you quoted at Answer? The solution should provide a means for expected result, if not exacting as to actual Question which you quoted.

Comment: @guest271314 A requirement is not a boundary. I'm trying to solve problems instead of taking everything literally.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, though why load the `.js` file at browsers where the file is not necessary? You can check `document.body.style` for an `MS` prefixed property and  then request file if the condition is `true`. Literal interpretation avoids ambiguity as to a specific requirement or topic. Specificity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use

```html
<script>
    if (typeof Promise !== "function")
        document.write('<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/4.1.1/es6-promise.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

which does not work only for IE users, but in every environment without a native `Promise` implementation.

Comment: loaded script by `document.write` will be [blocked in chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104). It's ok for chrome since chrome has promise already. Does other browser has this issue?

Comment: @cwtuan The OPs `<script>` tag was synchronously loaded as well, so that's on purpose. If you want to avoid be blocked by ad-targeting features, you have to use a non-cdn version of the polyfill.

Comment: This created a function called ES6Promise instead of Promise.

Answer (score 1):

Same without the external script

```js
var lPromise = function(handler) {
  if (typeof Promise === "function")
    return new Promise(handler);
  var self = this;
  self._handler = handler;
  this.then = function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
    this._handler(onFulfilled, onRejected);
  }
  return self;
}
this.Promise = function(handler) {
  return new lPromise(handler);
}
```