# How to add preloader to long running function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I develop a custom html page with information about installed certificates on the local machine. The certificate's information I get by crypto provider api, then I filter returned certificates with some restrictions (Issuer, CommonName, etc). This is the work of my function `loadCertificates`. I show results on button click. But `loadCertificates` takes some seconds and I want to show preloader before  `loadCertificates` and hide after:

```
        $("#select__cert-btn").click(function () {
            showPreloader();
            var certificates = loadCertificates(restrictions);
            hidePreloader();
            showCerificates(certificates);
        });
```

Functions `showPreloader` and `hidePreloader` only add/remove div with gif background to the container with certificates info. But when I click on the button my page seems frozen and only after some seconds show results (without appearing my preloader). But in debug mode, before run `loadCertificates` the preloader is added to html, but it's not visible.

Early I have never the same problem, but it seems like `loadCertificates` block main thread, but if I'm right why `showPreloader` not work correclty?

How to solve my problem?

Comment: If `loadCertificates` is asynchronous, then it is impossible for you to wait for its result unless the function returns a Promise, or has callback

Comment: It looks like `loadCertificates` is *not* asynchronous.  You need to give the browser time to update your preloader.  Wrap all the code after showPreloader() in a `setTimeout` to allow the browser to update.  There's a duplicate I read yesterday, which I'll try to find, so not a full answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery/Javascript - How to wait for manipulated DOM to update before proceeding with function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342084/jquery-javascript-how-to-wait-for-manipulated-dom-to-update-before-proceeding)

Comment: @freedomn-m, it not helps. When I reached line with `loadCertificates` gif blocked

Comment: By "blocked" I assume you mean: "gif is now shown, but doesn't animate" - well that's the browser / plugin locking up your browser and nothing you can do about it other than changing how `loadCertificates` works.

Comment: @freedomn-m, you are absolutely right. Thank you. I will research `loadCertificates `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use a promise so that the loadCertificates runs async without locking the main thread.

Try this:

```
$("#select__cert-btn").click(function () {
    showPreloader();
    var certificates = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       loadCertificates(restrictions);
       resolve();
    });
    certificates.then(function(result) {
        hidePreloader();
        showCerificates(certificates);
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I use IE 11 :(

Comment: you could try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509701/elegant-way-to-include-es6-promise-for-ie

Answer (score 0):

if your loadCertificates function call an endpoint via ajax then you can simply add a html region that will be hide/shown with a gif image (loading) :

```
<!-- Will be called on every ajax call to show the spinner -->
    <div class="row" id="ajaxLoading" style="display:none">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-4">
            <img src="~/Images/loading.gif" />
        </div>

    </div>
```

then add in your scipt file :

```
var ajaxLoading = $('#ajaxLoading');
//add a spinner to every ajax call
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        ajaxLoading.show();
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        ajaxLoading.hide();
    });
```

Comment: I don't use ajax

Comment: how are you calling your API then ?

Comment: API connected with plugin installed in browser. I use only one function plugin.Store.Open()

Comment: your approach should work, if whatever loadCertificates() does is synchronous.

If it isn't, then you will need to call the hidePreloader() method in a callback that fires when the operation (loadCertificates ) finishes.